# dataSource for mat-table not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular 8 based project, following files are created.

Mat-table is not showing any data at all. It shows an empty table and there are no errors.

What am I missing here?

**Angular component HTML content**

```
...
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
...
```

**Component TS file**

```
...
export class DealersListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.loadDealers();
}

loadDealers() {
    const subscription: Subscription = this.dealerService.getDealers(this.result).subscribe(data => {
      this.result.fromJson(data as DealersPageResults);
      this.dealers = this.result.records as Dealer[];
      if (this.dealers && this.dealers.length) {
        this.isDataloaded = true;
        this.dataSource = this.dealers;
      }
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

**dealer.service.ts**

```
import { Dealer } from '@shared/models/app.model';
...
type DealersPageResults = PageResults<Dealer, {}>;
...
export class DealerService {
...
  getDealers(result: DealersPageResults): Observable<DealersPageResults> {
    // this.logger.log(`getDealers() - API endpoint --> ${this.dealersUrl}`);
    return this.http
      .get<DealersPageResults>(this.dealersUrl, result.query());
  }
...
}
```

**app.model.ts**

```
export interface Dealer extends ModelType {
  name: string;
  country: string;
  countryCode: string;
  mbID: string; // in old app this is 'code' field
  city: string;
  website: string;
  phone: string;
  status: string;
  email: string;
  description?: string; // Description
  address: string;
  postalCode: string;
  contacts: Array<DealerContactPerson>;
  passengerCar: boolean;
  van: boolean;
  truck: boolean;
  bus: boolean;
  unimog: boolean;
  gssnID: string; // outletID in the old app
  companyID: string;
  createdBy?: string;
  lastUpdatedBy?: string;
  state?: DealerState;
  business?: string;
}
```

Comment: if you add a console log statement inside your subscription, are you seeing data returned from the service?

Comment: @Edward I can see that data is being returned from the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added, removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the table's rendered rows by calling its renderRows() method.
>   [Source](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data)

**Angular component HTML content**

```
...
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
...
```

**Fichier TS composant**

```
...
export class DealersListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
...

@ViewChild('table', {static: false}) table: MatTable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.loadDealers();
}

loadDealers() {
    const subscription: Subscription = this.dealerService.getDealers(this.result).subscribe(data => {
      this.result.fromJson(data as DealersPageResults);
      this.dealers = this.result.records as Dealer[];
      if (this.dealers && this.dealers.length) {
        this.isDataloaded = true;
        this.dataSource = this.dealers;
        this.table.renderRows();
      }
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```